# WinUI PasswordBox Text Resources

Tags: text, winui-3, uid, passwordbox

I am trying to define a setting page that includes a PasswordBox element. When I Rebuild the app, the defined Text resources do not show properly. However, if I remove the:

```
    x:Uid="/resources/db_pwd"
```

definition (see below) then it Rebuilds the view OK. If I try to initialize the view with the resource link defined then I get the error below. It appears as if a Text property for the PasswordBox ... but it does not have this property. Very confused!

### Resources

```
|Name                   |   Value                   |
|-----------------------|---------------------------|
|db_pwd.Header          |Password (default password)|
|db_pwd.PlaceholderText |Enter your password        |
|db_pwd.Text            |Password (default pwd)     |
```

### Password Box

```
    <PasswordBox x:Name="dbpwd" Width="300" x:Uid="/resources/db_pwd"  
      Header="Database Password"    
      PlaceholderText="Enter password"  
      PasswordChanged="PasswordBox_PasswordChanged"  
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,5,0,0" />
```

### Error Initializing View

```
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException 
    HResult=0x802B000A 
    Message=The text associated with this error code could not be found. 
    Unable to resolve property 'Text' while processing properties for Uid '/sql/db_pwd'. [Line: 38 Position: 68] 
      Source=Windows 
      StackTrace: 
       at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator,   ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)
       at WeeWX.Views.SettingsPage.InitializeComponent() in D:\Dave\Documents\Visual Studio\WeeWX\obj\x86\Debug\Views\SettingsPage.g.i.cs:line 49 
       at WeeWX.Views.SettingsPage..ctor() in D:\Dave\Documents\Visual Studio\WeeWX\Views\SettingsPage.xaml.cs:line 49
       at WeeWX.Views.MainPage.SetSettings(Object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) in D:\Dave\Documents\Visual Studio\WeeWX\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 350
    This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
     [External Code]
    WeeWX.Views.SettingsPage.SettingsPage() in SettingsPage.xaml.cs 
    WeeWX.Views.MainPage.SetSettings(object, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs) in MainPage.xaml.cs
```

### Questions

1. Why is it looking for a Text property, Password Box does not have this property!?
2. It fails even if I add a Text entry in the resources file as shown. Why?
3. What is the root cause of this error, and the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed this issue, but the scenario is important:

1. The original definition was a `TextBox`, which I then changed to `PasswordBox`
2. This is when Visual Studio (VS) was still looking to resolve a `Text` property (of the `TextBox` I assume vs the `PasswordBox.Content` property), therefore I thought there must be some caching going on.
3. I tried to do the Build/Clean Solution thing, with no success
4. I then did #3 again, restarted VS, still no success
5. I then did #3 again, changed the name of the `db_pwd` resources and reference to `db_pswd`, deleted `db_pwd.Text`, rebuilt the solution and ... success!

Not sure exactly what steps are required to fix this sort of issue, but the bottom line is that VS has some really dumb (overly optimistic) caching going on! Comments or advice?

PS: Now have a similar issue after changing a `TextBox` to `HyperlinkButton`. Fixed through a similar process (step #5)!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

> 1.Why is it looking for a Text property, Password Box does not have this property!?
> 2.It fails even if I add a Text entry in the resources file as shown. Why?

The `PasswordBox` control doesn't have a `Text` property. It has a `Password` property.

> 3.What is the root cause of this error, and the fix?

To fix this error you need to change your resource:

`db_pwd.Text` -> `db_pwd.Password`

Comment: No, tried that. The error indicates that it is actually looking for 'Text'.

Comment: That's weird. I used your code in a blank project and all I needed to do is change your resource from ``Text`` to ``Password``.

Comment: It is a multilingual app, but I don't think that this is the issue. One thing I find confusing (new to Visual Studio) ... there seems to be some caching of the project build elements, yes? How can this be cleared.

Comment: Select **[Build]** > **[Clean Solution]** at the menu bar and **Rebuild** your solution.

Comment: Nope ... no success. And I though Android Studio was complex and dumb ... Visual Studio is much worse!

Comment: Can you share your (minimal) code that reproduce your problem? GitHub maybe?